# Parsing URL Links

Tags: sql-server, parse, split

```
 I have a large data set of over 10k+ rows and I'm trying to parse the url link
 that people of clicked on

 here is a table: dbo.email_list

 UserID   Cliked_Linked
 101012   https:// amz/profile_center?qp= 8eb6cbf33cfaf2bf0f51
 052469   htpps:// lago/center=age_gap=email_address=caipaingn4535=English_USA
 046894   https://itune/fr/unsub_email&utm=packing_345=campaign_6458_linkname=ghostrider
```

So I tried this code:

```
UPDATE email_list set Clicked_Link= REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Cliked_Link),,CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(ColumnName)) + 1, 999))
```

Unfortunately this didn't work.

The goal is to have the link split where the '=' sign is and and have anything that is between the equal sign be in its own column

```
This is the result I hope to have

UserID  COL_1                              COL_2                  COL_3                COL_4
101012  https:// amz/profile_center?qp    8eb6cbf33cfaf2bf0f51    NaN
052469  htpps:// lago/center              email_addres           caipaingn4535         English_USA
046894  https://itune/fr/unsub_email&utm  packing_345          campaign_6458_linknam   ghostrider
```

Comment: What version of SQL SERVER you have? 2017,2008?

Comment: How many = signs can there be?

Comment: @Edgar Vazquez, I'm using 2017

Comment: @scsimon some links have 3 and some others have 1

Comment: The answer from @Randi Vertongen is correct? or your expectic is another answer?

Comment: @Edgar Vazquez the one from is correct. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Thanks @Randi Vertongen for your help. I was able to parse my data set.

Comment: @learning great to hear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on SQL Server 2016 or above, you can use `STRING_SPLIT()` in combination with `PIVOT`. You would have to know how many `=` signs you have though.

```
SELECT UserID, Cliked_Linked, [1],[2],[3],[4],[5]
FROM
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY USERID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as rn
FROM dbo.email_list
CROSS APPLY
STRING_SPLIT(Cliked_Linked,'=')
) AS SourceT
PIVOT
(
MAX(value)
FOR rn IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5]) 
) as Pvt;
```

Example result set

[image]
[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e57ffb7ed5af6735fb1481470881c39d)